# Zoom graphics on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, zooming, affinetransform

I am currently trying to figure out how to zoom in a `JPanel` that has graphics drawn on it. The `JPanel` is currently embedded in a `JScrollPane`, which should allow the user to scroll when the zoom level is above 100%.

Right now, I am able to zoom in the panel properly, but the AffineTransform is not applied to the mouse events. Also, when the `scrollBars` are visible, they are way too long. I don't want them to be longer than the original size of the `JPanel`.

```
private AffineTransform m_zoom;

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics p_g) {
    if (m_mainWindow != null) {
        m_zoom = ((Graphics2D) p_g).getTransform();
        m_zoom.scale(m_scale, m_scale);
        ((Graphics2D) p_g).transform(m_zoom);

        super.paintComponent(p_g);
    }
    p_g.dispose();
}

public void setScale(double p_scale) {
    m_scale = p_scale;
    repaint();
    revalidate();
}
```

If someone could help me with all this, that would be very appreciated!
Thank you

Comment: Mouse events will *never* change to match your zoom. There is no concept of zoom in Swing. You have to do the math yourself in your (mouse) listeners. As for the scrollbars being "too long", again its *your code* that controls the preferred size of your panel - set it properly for the zoom level and the scrollbars will match it. Also you should *never* dispose the graphics object passed to your paintComponent method.

Comment: You can actually do what you're trying to do with the use of JXLayer/JLayer.  The linked duplicate question/answer has runnable example which will not only allow you to scale the graphics but also the events as they occur, what's really cool about this, is it works basically on all Swing based components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out what was going on with the `JScrollPane`. I adjusted the size of the `JPanel` manually according to new zoom level and it worked.

```
public void setScale(double p_newScale) {
    m_scale = p_newScale;
    int width = (int) (getWidth() * m_scale);
    int height = (int) (getHeight() * m_scale);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    repaint();
    revalidate();
}
```

I still need to find a way to calculate the position of the mouse with the `JPanel` zoomed in/out. Should I override the `mouseClicked` and `mouseMoved` methods directly in my custom `JPanel` class?

EDIT:

I used a simple division for the relative coordinates on my JPanel. It worked out very well for both mouseMoved and mouseClicked.

```
Point zoomedLocation = new Point((int)(evt.getPoint().x / m_zoomFactor),
            (int)(evt.getPoint().y / m_zoomFactor));
```

And I am using `zoomedLocation` everywhere instead of `evt.getPoint()`.